# Debug Ruby/Rails in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rspec, ide, cucumber

Because of this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512114/stack-level-too-deep-systemstackerror-when-using-both-rspec-and-cucumber-with), I would like to execute ruby code step-by-step while running rspec or cucumber.  Not only would I like to stop execution, but I would like to then proceed through the code, line by line.

Is there a best-practice-approach to step into code that is running while RAILS_ENV = 'test' ?  Is there any way to do this currently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[pry-debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) allows you to step through code line by line:

- `step`: Step execution into the next line or method. Takes an optional numeric argument to step multiple times.
- `next`: Step over to the next line within the same frame. Also takes an optional numeric argument to step multiple lines.
- `finish`: Execute until current stack frame returns.
- `continue`: Continue program execution and end the Pry session

Answer (score 3):

I use [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry), which opens an interpreter in your current console so that you can inspect the variables with their current values.

Just require the gem and put `binding.pry` inside your tests. The Readme file is quite self-explanatory, so I'll leave you to it :)

Comment: I looked at pry.  Seems great.  But, I don't see where it allows for stepwise code execution.  I'm looking to debug what I believe might be a cyclical chain of 'require thisFile.rb' commands or some other unintended recursion.  Pry looks great at inspecting state and more, but will it provide me a trace of the execution path or some IDE like 'now I am at this line of code' insight?

Comment: Damn, it looks like I missed the link :( I was actually meaning pry-debugger and got pry instead, sorry :( Anyway, I'm glad you found pry-debugger useful, it's a really nice tool :)

Comment: No problem.  I'll be including both in my future rails work.  Very handy.  Thanks again.